# hello , i accidentally sent token from metamask to a token contract , can i get them back?

Tags: metamask, smart-contract-wallets

this is the contract address, is there a possibility to recover them?

0x2cD96e8C3FF6b5E01169F6E3b61D28204E7810Bb

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say this. But contracts often don't have a "returnMoney" functions. Thus all tokens sent to their address are locked there.

Comment: I start by thanking you. do you think anyone can see if this contract has this "return money" feature?

Comment: I did take a look at it over ETHSCAN-> https://etherscan.io/address/0x2cD96e8C3FF6b5E01169F6E3b61D28204E7810Bb However the address you posted doesn't seem to belong to any contract. (At least not on the ETH network)